# Написание дроби c++

Tags: c++, математика

Как в c++ написать дробь, чтобы знаменатель был под числителем?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду? Просто вывести в текстовом режиме? в три строки... Так первые Mathematica работали - страшно смотреть было :) Если неверно вас понял - уточните вопрос, pls...

Comment: Да, в текстовом режиме

Comment: Вам нужно одиночные дроби выводить или в составе выражения?

Comment: @velikodniy в составе выражения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За отсутствием форматирования в комментариях вынужден прибегнуть к ответу :)

В тексте - если `a/b` никак не устраивает - только в первой строке выводить знаменатель, во второй - рисовать знак дроби, и в третьей - числитель...

```
5   8    31
- + - =  --
2   3     6
```

Примерно так...

Comment: И это компилируется? )

Comment: @gil9red казалось бы при чем тут вывод и компиляция?

Comment: @gil9red `cout << "5   8   31\n- + - = --\n2   3    6\n"` - вполне, почему бы и нет?...